# How do I print just the first 300 characters?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, character, gettext

I am working on a project that prints the first 300 characters on a specific web page. My code works for the most part but the issue I'm running into is how do I print just the first 300 characters instead of the entire page?

```
gen_random = str(random.randint(2000,8001))                             

new_url = ('http://www.gutenberg.org/files/'+ gen_random + '/'+ 
gen_random + '.txt')                 

html = urllib.request.urlopen(new_url)                

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')                 

print(soup.find('body').getText())
```

Comment: `print(soup.find('body').getText()[:300])`?

Comment: This worked! Thank you. I had tried putting it inside the first set of parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

```
print(soup.find('body').getText()[:300])
```